# Donation Page on Wordpress Website integrated with CCAvenue

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, custom-wordpress-pages, ccavenue

I'm trying to create a webpage on Wordpress website, where a potential donor can write their name, contact details and the amount (in USD) that they would like to donate.
Once the user clicks on the Donate button, they should be able to make the donation through CCAvenue Payment Gateway.

The problem is, none of the solutions that I have found so far tell me how can I keep the field of Donation Amount open to the user and how can I send these variables to CCAvenue API.

Any suggestions on how to do it, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am also trying to do the same I found one cool plugin which is GiveWP you can create a donate forms and integrate plenty of payment gateway addons, including the CCAvenue Gateway addon.
Check it out here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/give/
Hope this helps you :)